# Java: System.arraycopy for 2 parts of array

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose I have an array declared as

```
int[] unordered = {3, 4, 5, 1, 2};
```

and I want to create a new array, a, with a size 25% greater than that of `unordered` which has the original contents in order, followed by the indices that have not yet been assigned a value (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0). How would I do this using System.arraycopy? Currently, what I have is:

```
int[] a = new int[(int)(unordered.length*.25)];
System.arraycopy(items, 3, a, 0, unordered.length-3);
System.arraycopy(items, 0, a, unordered.length-3, 3);
```

When I run this code, I get an array out of bounds error.

Comment: Multiply by `1.25` in order to make the array 25% larger. Right now you are making it smaller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
int[] a = new int[(int)(unordered.length*.25)];
```

To:

```
int[] a = new int[(int)(unordered.length*1.25) + 1];
```

As int cast is lowering the number (for example 3.5 -> 3 etc.) you should add one to the array size.

Also multiply by 1.25 in order to increase the array size as multiply by 0.25 is decreasing the size.

Comment: I also just realized I had to multiply by 1.25 and not 0.25-- silly mistake. Thank you, it works now!